# Expand the function $[\cos(x^3)]^\frac{-1}{2}$ into Taylor series around $x=0$ up to $O(x^6)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

I need help in expansion of the following function into Taylor Series up to $O(x^6)$
$$[\cos(x^3)]^\frac{-1}{2}$$
The things I've already tried are expansion of $u^\frac{-1}{2}$ by assuming $u=cos(x^3)$ and manually calculated 4 differentials of $u^\frac{-1}{2}$ and writing their Taylor's expansion without inputing $u=0$
The Taylor expansion looks something like $$\frac{(u-a)^0}{0!}u^\frac{-1}{2} - \frac{(u-a)^1}{1!}\frac{1}{2}u^\frac{-3}{2} +\frac{(u-a)^2}{2!}\frac{3}{4}u^\frac{-5}{2}-\frac{(u-a)^3}{3!}\frac{15}{8}u^\frac{-7}{2}+\cdots$$
Initially i though of substituting $u$ as Taylor series of $\cos(x^3)$ as $$\cos(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{t^{2k}}{2k!}$$ by inputting $t=x^3$ so it becomes $$\cos(x^3) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{6k}}{2k!}$$

But this makes things more complicated than normal as $u$ is in root powers and I cannot figure out what can i do to reach to a solution to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Series[Cos[x^3]^(-1/2), {x, 0, 6}]` performs $$1+\frac{x^6}{4}+O\left(x^7\right).$$ Maple has  analog commands `taylor` and `series` to this end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\left[\cos(x^3)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\implies \log(y)=-\frac{1}{2}\log\left[\cos(x^3)\right]$$
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\cos(x^3)=1-\frac{x^6}{2}+\frac{x^{12}}{24}+O\left(x^{15}\right)$$
$$\log\left[\cos(x^3)\right]=-\frac{x^6}{2}-\frac{x^{12}}{12}+O\left(x^{15}\right)$$
As, $\log(y)=-\frac{1}{2}\log\left[\cos(x^3)\right]$
$$\log(y)=\frac{x^6}{4}+\frac{x^{12}}{24}+O\left(x^{15}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=1+\frac{x^6}{4}+\frac{7 x^{12}}{96}+O\left(x^{15}\right)=1+\frac{x^6}{4}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$

Comment: Isn't $\log(y) = -\frac{1}{2}\log[\cos(x^3)]$. Will we multiply the $\log[\cos(x^3)]$ series by $\frac{-1}{2}$ for calculating $\log(y)$ and then move forward with the expansion of $e^{\log(y)}$?

Comment: @Qhassan. Sorry for the typo. I'll fic it now.

Comment: would you mind explaining only the log part, when you took the $\log[\cos(x^3)]$? Which expression did you use for $\log(x)$ at x=0 and what's the intuition behind it?

Comment: @Qhassan. It is not $\log(x)$ but $\log(1+x)$

Comment: then can you please explain how can we make a $\log(1 + x)$ transformation from $\log(x)$, Do we need to add or subtract anything from the series?

Comment: @Qhassan. Look at $\cos(x^3)=\color{red}{1}+\cdots$

Comment: As we move from $\cos(x^3)$ to $\log[\cos(x^3)]$, by using $\log(1 + x)$, do we subtract 1 from each iteration of  $\log(x+1)$ expansion, and if yes, it becomes $(1 - \frac{x^6}{2} + \frac{x^12}{24}+ ...  \color{red}{-1}) + \frac{(1 - \frac{x^6}{2} + \frac{x^12}{24}+ ...  \color{red}{-1})^2}{2}+ ...$. Right?

Comment: And on the subsequent step, when we are calculating $\log(y)$, won't multiplying by $-\frac{1}{2}$ makes it $\log(y) = \frac{x^6}{\color{red}{4}} +  \frac{x^{12}}{\color{red}{24}} + ...$ ? Apologies, i'm a bit confused and I only want to clear some disambiguates in my brain, but your answer is the best answer I've received. It's intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=(\cos(x^3))^{-\frac 12}$

Then $\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac 12(\cos(x^3))^{-\frac 32}\sin(x^3)3x^2$ (using the chain rule)

Can you continue differentiating to get $\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}$, $\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}$ etc?

Comment: I mean I can use the traditional methods to calculate 1st, 2nd, 3rd, .... order differentials and then calculate their values at 0 and expand as Taylor series but, as you can see, even on the first differential, we have 3 functions in multiplication. Expansion in such a way won't be efficient let alone cumbersome. I am looking for Taylor series substitution methods to simplify the expansion, perhaps using expansion of one or more functions and combining them together through their general expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Combine
$\cos(x^3)
=1-x^6/2+O(x^{12})
$
with
$(1-z)^{-1/2}
=1+z/2+O(z^2)
$
to get
$1+x^6/4+O(x^{12})
$.

Comment: How can i substitute $\cos(x^3)$ in $(1-z)^\frac{-1}{2}$, can't it only be substituted for $z^\frac{-1}{2}$. What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: @Qhassan You substitute $z=-\cos(x^3)+1=x^6/2+\cdots$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for the clarification, I understand it now.